# How to ignore nulls in PostgreSQL window functions? or return the next non-null value in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have the following table:

```
 | User_id |   COL1   | COL2 |
 +---------+----------+------+
 | 1       |          | 1    |
 | 1       |          | 2    | 
 | 1       |   2421   |      | 
 | 1       |          | 1    | 
 | 1       |   3542   |      | 
 | 2       |          | 1    |
```

I need another column indicating the next non-null COL1 value for each row, so the result would look like the below:

```
 | User_id |   COL1   | COL2 | COL3 |
 +---------+----------+------+------
 | 1       |          | 1    | 2421 |
 | 1       |          | 2    | 2421 |
 | 1       |   2421   |      |      |
 | 1       |          | 1    | 3542 |
 | 1       |   3542   |      |      |
 | 2       |          | 1    |      |
```

---

```
SELECT 
first_value(COL1 ignore nulls) over (partition by user_id order by COL2 rows unbounded following) 
FROM table;
```

---

would work but I'm using PostgreSQL which doesn't support the ignore nulls clause.

Any suggested workarounds?

Comment: You need a column to specify the ordering.  SQL tables are inherently unordered.

Answer (score 20):

You can still do it with windowing function if you add a case when criteria in the order by like this:

```
select
   first_value(COL1) 
   over (
     partition by user_id 
     order by case when COL1 is not null then 0 else 1 end ASC, COL2 
     rows unbounded following
   ) 
from table
```

This will use non null values first.

However performance will probably not be great compared to `skip nulls` because the database will have to sort on the additional criteria.

Comment: But that's not really the same thing as the `IGNORE NULLS` clause.

Comment: A clause that postgresql does not support atm

Answer (score 9):

I also had the same problem. The other solutions may work, but I have to build multiple windows for each row I need.

You can try this snippets : https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)

If you create the aggregates you can use them:

```
SELECT 
first(COL1) over (partition by user_id order by COL2 rows unbounded following) 
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is always the tried and true approach of using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.col1
        from t t2
        where t2.id >= t.id and t2.col1 is not null
        order by t2.id desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as nextcol1
from t;
```

Comment: The t.id in the t2.id >= t.id filter isn't being found when I run this

Comment: @user3558238 . . . What do you mean it isn't being found?  `t` is the alias of the table in the outer query; `t2` is the alias in the inner query.

Comment: it's saying the t.user_id does not exist, perhaps subqueries can't refer to outer query parameters in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @user3558238 . . . Postgres definitely supports correlated subqueries.  You should edit your question and include your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

1. Aggregate functions can be used as window functions
2. There's an aggregate [`filter` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).
3. Window spec can tell it to order most recent first. [Get them](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ym4C9-B2) into an array:

```sql
select (array_agg(COL1)filter(where COL1 is not null)over w1)[1]
from cte
window w1 as (order by d desc rows 
              between current row and unbounded following);
```

4. You pop the `array[1]`.

Comment: Nice thing is, it's not just `skip nulls`, it's anything you can express in the `where` and it combines `lag`, `lead`, `first`, `last` and `nth_value` being able to target any position, which can also be an expression switching it dynamically. Looks and performance aside, one downside might be that if you want a negative subscript (supported for `json` arrays but not for the regular ones), you need to flip the window, or aggregate to `json` array, or bounce off of upper bound: `(array_agg()over w1)[count()over w1 -3]` or repeat `array_agg()` and take its `array_upper()`.

Answer (score -2):

Hope this helps,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY COALESCE(colA, colB);
```

which orders by colA and if colA has NULL value it orders by colB.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `COALESCE()` function. For your query:

```
SELECT 
first_value(COALESCE(COL1)) over (partition by user_id order by COL2 rows unbounded following) 
FROM table;
```

but i don't understand what the reason to use sort by COL2, because this rows has null value for COL2:

```
 | User_id |   COL1   | COL2 |
 +---------+----------+------+
 | 1       |          | 1    |
 | 1       |          | 2    | 
 | 1       |   2421   |      | <<--- null?
 | 1       |          | 1    | 
 | 1       |   3542   |      | <<--- null?
 | 2       |          | 1    |
```