# SQL: Get the latest value from all rows but ignore nulls

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

I'm inserting a new row per order update so I can keep track of the state updates. Like this.

```
+----------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
| event_id |   state   | amount |        address        |         notes         |            timestamp             |
+----------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
| order123 | fulfilled | NULL   | NULL                  | NULL                  | 2022-07-01T17:08:12.032316+00:00 |
| order123 | NULL      | NULL   | NULL                  | Delivered to customer | 2022-07-01T17:07:12.032316+00:00 |
| order123 | NULL      | NULL   | 300 Post St, CA 94108 | NULL                  | 2022-07-01T17:06:12.032316+00:00 |
| order123 | accepted  | NULL   | NULL                  | NULL                  | 2022-07-01T17:05:12.032316+00:00 |
| order123 | pending   | 100    | NULL                  | NULL                  | 2022-07-01T17:04:12.032316+00:00 |
+----------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
```

How would I write a query that pulls out the latest value from each of those columns, ignoring the NULLs. This is what I'm looking for.

```
+----------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
| event_id |   state   | amount |        address        |         notes         |            timestamp             |
+----------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
| order123 | fulfilled | 100    | 300 Post St, CA 94108 | Delivered to customer | 2022-07-01T17:08:12.032316+00:00 |
+----------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
```

This is as far as I've gotten, which gives me the latest record:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (event_id)
    event_id, state, amount, address, notes, timestamp
    FROM event_order
ORDER BY event_id, timestamp DESC;
```

DB Fiddle link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pZFUG96oYh6ymAz99vvqWh/0

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893970/last-value-with-ignore-nulls-in-sql-server) which mentions `LAST_VALUE` but the solution seems like it only works with integers.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6d839b24806e92e74200fb734a5bcc6e)

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    event_id,
    first_value(state) OVER (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY CASE WHEN state IS NOT NULL THEN
            0
        ELSE
            1
        END ASC, timestamp DESC),
    first_value(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY CASE WHEN amount IS NOT NULL THEN
            0
        ELSE
            1
        END ASC, timestamp DESC),
    first_value(address) OVER (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY CASE WHEN address IS NOT NULL THEN
            0
        ELSE
            1
        END ASC, timestamp DESC),
    first_value(notes) OVER (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY CASE WHEN notes IS NOT NULL THEN
            0
        ELSE
            1
        END ASC, timestamp DESC),
    first_value(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY CASE WHEN timestamp IS NOT NULL THEN
            0
        ELSE
            1
        END ASC, timestamp DESC)
FROM
    event_order;
```

credit: [PostgreSQL: order by column, with specific NON-NULL value LAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193339/postgresql-order-by-column-with-specific-non-null-value-last)            [How to ignore nulls in PostgreSQL window functions? or return the next non-null value in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470931/how-to-ignore-nulls-in-postgresql-window-functions-or-return-the-next-non-null)

Comment: This should return `accepted` and `101` but instead returns `pending` and `101`. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b2GXwLNzXjWwGSUQBv1XU/0

Comment: @realph Hi there. But **accepted** row the column amount is null.  So it should return **pending**.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1fd49ac7bf5cd4bfa7844eca666a6d6c

Comment: Still only showing `pending`

Comment: @realph sorry. I misunderstand your  requirement. hope the rewritten query is ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try aggregating with a `GROUP BY` clause. This will work on the state because the minimum between "*accepted*" and "*pending*" is the former. At the same time, the `MAX` aggregation function will skip NULL values completely.

```
SELECT event_id, 
       MIN(state), 
       MAX(amount),
       MAX(timestamp)
FROM event_order
GROUP BY event_id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ED9epJTkCHFwbXjG5cGci/1).

Comment: That WHERE clause gets me back the 2nd row (pending).

Comment: Check the edited answer.

Comment: If I add another entry to that demo with `fulfilled`, it still only returns the `accepted` record. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/evCCPZ16GefHJ6PGBLP3z2/0

Comment: You should update your post with fully-standalone borderline sample data with **at least** ten rows on different "*event_id*" values and the corresponding expected output, otherwise we can have back and forth of answers and wrong outcomes, wasting others', my and your very own time.

Comment: Updated original post. Thanks!